# Cannot insert image in k2 article

Tags: javascript, joomla-3.9

I'm facing an issue on the backend side of my Joomla 3.9.
I'm using K2 as the content builder and set TinyMCE as default editor. I wanted to insert an image by using the modal button "image", but, as I'm in the popup window and I select an image, neither the "insert" button nor the exit one works.

Particularly I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.jInsertEditorText is not a function
>       at Object.onok (popup-imagemanager.min.js?4a006a4cdc5a805)

Here below a screenshot of what the situation looks like
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?